# Finding an integer-coefficients quadratic equation which has approximate solutions of $e$ and $\pi$.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

**Question** : Find a quadratic polynomial $f(x)=a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0\ (a_i\in\mathbb Z)$ which has the following three conditions.

Suppose that $f(x)=0$ gives two real positive solutions $\alpha, \beta.$

Here, note that $2.71828 1\lt e\lt 2.718282$ and $3.141592\lt \pi\lt 3.141593$.

Condition 1 : $2.7182\lt \alpha \lt 2.7183$.

Condition 2 : $3.1415\lt \beta \lt 3.1416$.

Condition 3 : $H:=|a_2|+|a_1|+|a_0|$ is min.

**Example** : I found the following.

$1605x^2-9405x+13706=0$ has solutions $x=2.71827\cdots, x=3.14153\cdots$. $H=24716.$

I don't know if this is the answer for the above question.

**Motivation** : First, I was interested in finding the following polynomials, which are what I've found.

*1.* $35x^2-83x-33=0$ has a solution $x=2.71828\cdots$.

*2.* $19x^2-39x-65=0$ has a solution $x=3.14158\cdots$.

*3.* $45x^2-121x-64=0$ has a solution $x=3.14159\cdots$. $H=230$.

*4.* $41x^2-47x-257=0$ has a solution $x=3.14159\cdots$. $H=345$.

Then, I got interested in the above question.

Comment: I think it's possible just to write a program that goes through all possible integer coefficients (your solution provides an upper estimation for the sum of absolute values of those coefficients, so the number of possibilities is finite) and checks whether the roots satisfy your conditions.

Comment: I would try getting a convergent to desired accuracy using continued fractions for $e+\pi$ and $e \times \pi$ (or for them individually), and form the quadratic using those rationals to get coefficients (using Vieta's formulae).

Comment: @Macavity The first approximation of continued fractions are 355/113 and 1264/465 respectively ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe ... and the quadratic which has those roots is then easily constructed as $52545 x^2- 307907 x + 448720$. While this is easy, clearly the coefficients are too large to be considered optimal :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I performed an exhaustive search of all quadratic equations $a\,x^2-b\,x+c=0$ with

1. $1\le a\le 24716$
2. $2.7182+3.1415<b/a<2.7183+3.14156$
3. $2.7182\times 3.1415<c/a<\min(2.7183\times 3.14156,24716-a-b)$

and found the smallest $H$ corresponds to
$$
1455\,x^2 - 8526\,x + 12425 = 0
$$
with solutions 
$$x_1=2.71829117343,\quad x_2=3.14150264101$$
and
$$
H=22406.
$$

Comment: Nice! thank you very much.